# Custom Python module not importing

Tags: python, debugging, import, module, runtime-error

I can't seem to get past this and do not quite understand what is happening. I have a directory with two class files in it. Using the REPL from within that directory I can import both files and execute their logic. From their parent directory which main() is ran from however, only one class file is visible, pagetable.

The project structure is currently,

```
project/
    src/
        __init__.py # empty
        pagingsimulation.py # main() imports memory
        process.py
        memory/
            __init__.py # imports pagetable.py
            pagetable.py # visible
            page.py # error
```

pagingsimulation.py was able import memory/ and instantiate pagetable.PageTable, but once I created page.py and had pagetable.py import page.py, pagingsimulation.py now throws this error upon execution.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pagingsimulator.py", line 5, in <module>
    import memory
  File "src/memory/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pagetable import PageTable
  File "src/memory/pagetable.py", line 1, in <module>
    import page
ImportError: No module named 'page'
```

within memory/__init__.py I currently have,

```
    from .pagetable import PageTable
```

...but have tried many other variations without success.

I've tried multiple approaches and have researched this for awhile and perhaps it is something I just cannot see at this point. What is preventing my custom modules from importing each other when ran from main()?

Comment: According to the directory layout at the top, `src` and `memory` are sibling directories, however the traceback refers to `src/memory/...`

Comment: `import page` will only work if the parent directory (`project/src/memory`) is on your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @JohnGordon That was a formatting error. Thanks for catching. memory is a subdirectory to src, (i.e., project/src/memory/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as I suspected was a pathing issue and more specifically in relation to how the modules interact once imported into the parent file, pagingsimulation.py.

So to resolve this issue it had nothing to do with __init__.py but rather how I was accessing page.py from within pagetable.py

So pagingsimulator.py uses,

```
import memory
```

And within memory, the **init**.py file has,

```
from .pagetable import PageTable
```

For PageTable to access Page, the import statement had to be,

```
from memory import Page
```

It seems a bit funky to me and after failing so many times I would like to say there is a cleaner way to do this, but for the time being I'll take my win and hope that leaving this question here benefits someone else as I was unable to find something similar during my search.