# Custom Module Import Issue

Tags: python

I can't seem to import my own custom NYT module. My project structure is as follows and I'm on a mac:

```
articulation/
    articulation/
        __init__.py # empty
        lib/
            nyt.py
            __init__.py # empty
        tests/
            test_nyt.py
            __init__.py # empty
```

When I try running `python articulation/tests/test_nyt.py` from that first parent directory, I get

```
  File "articulation/tests/test_nyt.py", line 5, in <module>
    from articulation.lib.nyt import NYT
    ImportError: No module named articulation.lib.nyt
```

I also tried

```
(venv) Ericas-MacBook-Pro:articulation edohring$ Python -m articulation/tests/test_nyt.py 
/Users/edohring/Desktop/articulation/venv/bin/Python: Import by filename is not supported.
```

test_nyt.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../../')
import unittest
#from mock import patch
# TODO: store example as fixture and complete test

from articulation.lib.nyt import NYT

class TestNYT(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('articulation.lib.nyt.NYT.fetch')
    def test_nyt(self):
        print "hi"
        #assert issubclass(NYT, Article)
        # self.assertTrue(sour_surprise.title == '')"""


nyt.py

        from __future__ import division

import regex as re
import string
import urllib2
from collections import Counter

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from cookielib import CookieJar

PARSER_TYPE = 'html.parser'


class NYT:
    def __init__(self, title, url):
        self.url = url
        self.title = title
        self.words = get_words(url)


def get_words(url):
    cj = CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    p = opener.open(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(p.read(), PARSER_TYPE)
    # title = soup.html.head.title.string
    letters = soup.find_all('p', class_='story-body-text story-content')
    if len(letters)==0:
        letters = soup.find_all('p', class_='paragraph--story')
    if len(letters)==0:
        letters = soup.find_all('p', class_='story-body-text', )
    words = Counter()
    for element in letters:
        a = element.get_text().split()
        for c in a:
            c = ''.join(ch for ch in c if c.isalpha())
            c = c.lower()
            if len(c) > 0: 
                words[c] += 1
    return words



def test_nyt():
    china_apple_stores = NYT('title_test', 'http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/29/technology/iphone-china-apple-stores.html?_r=0')
    assert(len(china_apple_stores.words) > 0)
    # print china_apple_stores.words
    fri_brief = NYT('Russia, Syria, 2017: Your Friday Briefing', 'http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/30/briefing/us-briefing-russia-syria-2017.html')
    assert(fri_brief.title == 'Russia, Syria, 2017: Your Friday Briefing')
    assert(fri_brief.url == 'http://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/30/briefing/us-briefing-russia-syria-2017.html')
    assert(len(fri_brief.words) > 0)
    vet = NYT('title_test', 'http://lens.blogs.nytimes.com/2017/01/03/a-love-story-and-twins-for-a-combat-veteran-amputee/')
    assert(len(vet.words)>0)
    print "All NYT Tests Passed"




#test_nyt()
```

I've tried the following and none seem to work - does anyone know how to fix this?
- [Adding an **init**.py file to the top directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638346/imports-custom-module-python) -> Doesn't help
- [Entering Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288860/custom-python-module-not-importing) Python couldn't find this - maybe because I'm using Python 2. If this is the issue I can post more what I tried. 
- Adding sys.path at the top from suggestion below

Comment: Relative imports make this fairly straightforward (albeit with an initial learning curve): `from ..lib.nyt import NYT`

Comment: Judging by the forward slashes, you are on a non-windows system. Your current directory may not be in the Python path. Try running `python -c 'import articulation'` from the command line and see if you get an error.

Comment: Tried the relative import and didn't work:                                                 (venv) edohring-mbp1:articulation edohring$ Python articulation/tests/test_nyt.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "articulation/tests/test_nyt.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..lib.nyt import NYT
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
(venv) edohring-mbp1:articulation edohring$ pwd
/Users/edohring/Desktop/articulation

Comment: No error from ' python -c 'import articulation'

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../../')
```

is usually a bad idea. Sometimes it's useful for when you're testing something, or you have a single-use program that you just need to work for a short time and then you're going to throw away, but in general it's a bad habit to get into because it might stop working once you move directories around or once you give the code to someone else. I would advise you not to let yourself get in the habit of doing that.

The most likely reason to get the kind of error you're seeing is that the directory `/Users/edohring/Desktop/articulation` does not appear in `sys.path`. The first thing to do is see what actually is in `sys.path`, and one good way to do that is to **temporarily** put these lines at the top of `test_nyt.py`:

```
import os.path, sys
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
    if not os.path.isabs(p):
        print('  (absolute: {})'.format(os.path.abspath(p)))
sys.exit()
```

Then run

```
python articulation/tests/test_nyt.py
```

and look at the output. You will get a line for each directory path that Python looks in to find its modules, and if any of those paths are relative, it will also print out the corresponding absolute path so that there is no confusion. I suspect you will find that `/Users/edohring/Desktop/articulation` does not appear anywhere in this list.

If that turns out to be the case, the most straightforward (but least future-proof) way to fix it is to run

```
export PYTHONPATH=".:$PYTHONPATH"
```

in the shell (not in Python!) before you use Python itself to do anything using your module. Directories named in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable will be added to `sys.path` when Python starts up. This is only a temporary fix, unless you put it in a file like `$HOME/.bashrc` which will get read by the shell every time you open up a Terminal window. You can read about this and [better ways to add the proper directory to `sys.path` in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797974/proper-initialization-of-sys-path-when-main-script-is-in-a-submodule).

Perhaps a better way to run your script is to use the shell command

```
python -m articulation.tests.test_nyt
```

This needs to be run in the directory `/Users/edohring/Desktop/articulation`, or at least that directory needs to appear in `sys.path` in order for the command to work. But using the `-m` switch in this way causes Python to handle how it sets up `sys.path` a little differently, and it may work for you. You can read more about [how `sys.path` is populated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38403654/56541).